# Chrome Extension : chrome.runtime.getURL getting the URL correctly on console.log but is not working when used with fetch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension (content script), and I have a json file I would like to include (and read from main js file).

Inside the manifest.json file, I have

```
"web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": ["data/info.json"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
}]
```

And in my main js file, I have

```
const jsonUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('data/info.json');
console.log(jsonUrl);
fetch(jsonUrl)
```

Console prints out the path as expected `chrome-extension://<extension-UUID>/data/info.json`

However, upon fetch is called, I get error

> GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED

I also get TypeError: Failed to fetch, but I believe that is because of the URL issue listed above.

Also tried jQuery but no luck.

```
$.getJSON(jsonUrl), function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

**Why am I passing invalid chrome-extension url to fetch method?**

Comment: Sounds like you edited manifest.json but didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: @wOxxOm I can definitely guarantee that I have reloaded multiple times

Comment: Then the path is incorrect.

Comment: @wOxxOm if so, why would it display the proper location with console.log?

Comment: Because getURL just adds a string to your string, it doesn't check the path's existence.

Comment: @wOxxOm the path is relative path from where the manifest.json right? If so, it should be correct...

Comment: Well, the only other option is a bug in the browser which you can report on https://crbug.com.

Comment: But first make sure web_accessible_resources is not inside some other key...

Comment: @wOxxOm ahhhhhhhh that was it. I thought it is supposed to be inside the content_scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @wOxxOm found the issue.

"web_accessible_resources" was inside the "content_scripts".